# Executing a Stored Procedure from EntityFramework - Code First

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have a SQL Stored Procedure (SP) **uspGetLocationsforUser**, which I am trying from my MVC Project.

I first mapped it into EntityFramework by adding this code to the Context Class (DAL):

```
public virtual ObjectResult<uspGetLocationsforUser_Result> uspGetLocationsforUser(string userName)
{
    var userNameParameter = userName != null ?
        new ObjectParameter("UserName", userName) :
        new ObjectParameter("UserName", typeof(string));

    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<uspGetLocationsforUser_Result>("uspGetLocationsforUser", userNameParameter);
}
```

This class was added to the model, to represent the returned result of the SP:

```
public class uspGetLocationsforUser_Result
{
    public int LocationID { get; set; }
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to call this from code, and for some reason this didn't work:

I am trying to do this:

```
using (var data = new DAL())
{
List<uspGetLocationsforUser_Result> results = data.uspGetLocationsforUser(userName).ToList(); 
}
```

Could you please help?

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

This is the error message:

"The FunctionImport 'uspGetLocationsforUser' could not be found in the container 'DAL'."

Comment: What exactly was the problem?

Comment: Is there somekind of error? (also, create a constructor under the uspGetLocationsforUser_Result class.

Comment: @RePierre I have updated the question to add the error message.

Comment: @Schuere The error is detailed in the update.

Comment: the error clearly states that your function doens't exist under EF. If you are using VS; try to update your model and add the procedure there. => EDIT; you can check this under the Model browser if your SPROC does exist under EF.

Comment: @Schuere this is a code-first. The function is part of DAL (context class).

Comment: @t_plusplus, my mistake, i was starting from a database-first approach

Comment: @Schuere its ok. I have found the answer as below. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this was that I had to add the SQL Schema name, under which the Stored Procedure belongs.

and then do this:

```
var userName = GetUserWindowsLoginName();

SqlParameter logonName = new SqlParameter("@userName", userName);

List<uspGetLocationsforUser_Result> results = data.Database.SqlQuery<uspGetLocationsforUser_Result>("admin.uspGetLocationsforUser @userName", logonName).ToList();
```

Comment: admin is the schema name in SQL Server!